# Conditional probability and independent variables

Tags: probability

If we defined

```
Pr(A) = 1/p, Pr(B) = 1/q
Event A = something and B = something
Event A and B are independent
```

and I am trying to determine Pr(A | A ∪ B)

What is the proper step I should take with the (A ∪ B)
Knowing Pr(A | B) = Pr(A) or Pr(B | A) = Pr(B) --> Because of the independence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent,
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) = \frac{1}{pq}$$

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) = \frac1p+\frac1q-\frac{1}{pq} = \frac{p+q-1}{pq}$$

$$P(A\mid A\cup B) \stackrel{*}= \frac{P(A)}{P(A\cup B)} = \frac{1/p}{(p+q-1)/(pq)} = \frac{q}{p+q-1}$$

To see why $(*)$ holds, it suffices to show that $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$ since $A \subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: Was just gonna ask you about the P(A∩(A∪B)), but you edited thanks this made it easier to understand

Comment: Wait you removed it, why is that?

Comment: @navinstudent You may think about the Venn diagram of $A \cap (A \cup B)$

Comment: @navinstudent I still dont understand how he went from P(A∣A∪B) to q/p+q−1

Comment: @AyeJay Sorry for my mistake in edition two.  As I've said, you may look at the Venn diagram to see why $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$

Comment: @AyeJay it is the basic definition of conditional probability

Comment: Thank you it took me a while to figure it out, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AyeJay Thanks for your accept.